# How to pass an object argument via signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals

Would it be possible to pass `point` object as an argument to `run` function? The code below results to `TypeError: signal() only accepts 0 arguments, 2 given!`

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

def run(arg = None, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'run:', arg, args, kwargs

class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal()

emitter = Emitter()
emitter.signal.connect(run)

point = QtCore.QPoint()
emitter.signal.emit(point)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the object you want to send. For example, to pass an int with a signal.

```
def Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(int)
```

I recommend reading more doc about this. For example, https://wiki.qt.io/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1.0:
Specify `object` as a type while declaring `signal = QtCore.Signal(object)`:

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

def run(arg = None, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'run:', arg, args, kwargs

class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(object) 

emitter = Emitter()
emitter.signal.connect(run)

point = QtCore.QPoint()

emitter.signal.emit(point)
```

Approach 1.1: Same approach is used to pass the multiple arguments:

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

def run(arg = None, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'run:', arg, args, kwargs

class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(object, object, str, int, dict, list, tuple) 

emitter = Emitter()
emitter.signal.connect(run)

point = QtCore.QPoint()
point2 = QtCore.QPoint()
emitter.signal.emit(point, point2, 'foo', 10, {1:'one'}, [1,2], (1, 2))
```

Approach 2:

Specify type `tuple` while declaring `signal`:

```
 signal = QtCore.Signal(tuple)
```

All the arguments passed should be followed by a comma: `...emit(point,)`

```
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

def run(arg = None, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'run:', arg, args, kwargs

class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    signal = QtCore.Signal(tuple) 

emitter = Emitter()
emitter.signal.connect(run)

point = QtCore.QPoint()

emitter.signal.emit(point,)
```